# Make variable not change when assign to another variable php

Tags: php

I have a problem in php like bellow

$test = 'test'

// I want to do something here to keep value of variable $test when I change code bellow.

$test = 'hello word';

print_r($test)

...
Any ideal to result of print_r($test) is 'test'.
Thanks.

Comment: I really don't understand this, could you provide context?

Comment: Before line $test = 'hello word'; I have a plugin and I want do something in this plugin to define const for variable $test to keep its value not change when we change code example $test = 'hello word'.

Comment: $test = $test!='test'?'test':'test'; ... sorry for the joke :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want your $test to be constant or what?

```
define("FOO",     "something");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but maybe you want to put your plugin stuff in a function? That way the $text variables will be protected by its scope:

```
$test = 'test';
echo "Test varable is initially: $test", PHP_EOL;

// I want to do something here to keep value of variable $test
// when I change code bellow.
$f = function () use ($test) {
    echo "Test in start of function: $test", PHP_EOL;
    $test = 'hello word'; // Plugin does something to $test
    echo "Test in function has changed to: $test", PHP_EOL;
};
$f(); // Call your function above with the plugin

echo "Test variable when returning from function is still: $test", PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Test varable is initially: test
Test in start of function: test
Test in function has changed to: hello word
Test variable when returning from function is still: test
```